# Copy and create a new line with paste VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want get a line in a exactly posiction on a sheet and transfer this insformation for another line, but in this line i need create this new line above another line and put this information.

The code is bellow:

```
Public Function getInformationInSheet()

    Dim Hostname As String
    Hostname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Value
    If MsgBox("Found a equal Mac, it's like " & Hostname & " do you want change this computer information? ", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Found a equal Mac Address") = vbYes Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -14).Value <> cmbDepartment.Value Then
            'Rows(ActiveCell.Rows).Cut Rows(findExactlyPosictionDepartment)
            range(ActiveCell.Address).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Cells(range(ActiveCell.Address), 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End If



End Function

Public Function findExactlyPosictionDepartment() As String

    findExactlyPosiction = ""
    Worksheets("Full Control").Activate
    range("A3").Select
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If ActiveCell.Value = cmbDepartment Then
            findExactlyPosictionDepartment = ActiveCell.Rows
            Exit Function
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Function
```

But when I runed this code I has a problem in this line:

```
Cells(range(ActiveCell.Address), 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

> The message is: Type mistach

Comment: The first argument of `Cells` should be the row number, not a range address.

Comment: But I need get the row number, and how can i do that, because I just have a ActiveCell

Comment: `ActiveCell.Row`?

Comment: Method Range of object '_Global' failed, I tryed do it bur i received this

Comment: `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a row index, not an instance of the `Range` class for the `Cells` property call:

```
Cells(range(ActiveCell.Address), 1)
```

with

```
Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: But i need receive this information of the where is the my cell, for a Function